# Ошибка private method `new' called for Prime Ruby

Tags: ruby

Что не так с этим кодом?

```
    require 'mathn'
    prime_number = Prime.new
```

Выводит ошибку:

```
`<top (required)>': private method `new' called for Prime:Class (NoMethodError)
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Я хочу чтобы он выписал простые числа меньше 90, но и без этой строчки все равно не работает

```
prime_number.each {|prime| print prime," ";break unless prime<90}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby не врёт. **У класса `Prime` [нет метода `new`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html#method-c-new).**

> #### new()
>
> obsolete. Use `Prime::instance` or class methods of `Prime`.

Точнее, есть, но спрятан, фактически запрещён к использованию. Да и не нужен.

Ваш код, скорее всего, тех времён, когда Ruby 1.8 был ещё актуальным. Но не в 2017 году же!

Скорее всего, вместо `prime_number` вам нужен сам `Prime`, в крайнем случае `Prime.instance`. Конкретно приведённый вами фрагмент кода отлично работает с `Prime`:

```
Prime.each {|prime| print prime," ";break unless prime<90}
```

Comment: Отлично! И в правду все работает! Спасибо!